# How do I determine that the function $f(x)=\sin3x+4\cos x-8x$ is decreasing on the entire real line?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

How do I determine (see) that the function $f(x)=\sin3x+4\cos x-8x$ is decreasing on the entire real line?

Its graph obviously helps, but I am not searching for that.

[image]

The only method I am familiar with is to find the solutions of the inequality $f'(x)<0$. In these intervals the function is decreasing. For the first derivative we have

$$f'(x)=3\cos3x-4\sin x-8$$ $$=3\left(4\cos^3x-3\cos x\right)-4\sin x-8$$$$=12\cos^3x-9\cos x-4\sin x-8$$

I am not sure the formula for $\cos3x$ helps whatsoever. It's not obvious for me that $f'(x)<0$ for all $x$. What's the idea?

Comment: As $-1 \le \cos 3x, \sin x \le 1$, it is easy to prove that $ f^\prime(x) \le -1$.

Comment: $f'$ is continuous and has no zeros. Therefore....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noticed in the fine comment by [mathcounterexamples.net](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/187663/mathcounterexamples-net) we simply have that

$$f'(x)=3\cos3x-4\sin x-8\le 3+4-8 =-1<0$$

therefore $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing.

In another way, we can write the function as follows

$$f(x)=\sin3x+4\cos x-8x =(\sin3x-3x)+4(\cos x-x)-x$$

and since the maximum slope of $\sin x$ is $1$ we can deduce, also without derivative, that the slope of $\sin x-x$ is not greater than $0$ and then that the slope of $f(x)$ is not greater than $-1$.

[image]